# Creating a bitmap using wxBitmap::NewFromPNGData method causes assert in wxWidgets 3.0

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I created a wxBitmap using `wxBitmap::NewFromPNGData` and `IsOk()` method returned false. My code is

```
static const unsigned char image_png[] = ...;
auto bitmap = wxBitmap::NewFromPNGData(image_png, WXSIZEOF(image_png));
```

`bitmap.IsOk()` returns `false`
What is wrong with this code? Is there another way to create bitmaps from hardcoded pngs?

Comment: Which port of wxWidgets do you use? Is this OS X by chance?

Comment: wxWidgets 3.0.0-RC1 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your wxWidgets was built without PNG support (which is very unlikely, as you need to explicitly disable it for this, it is enabled by default), the only explanation is the obvious one: your `image_png` doesn't contain valid data in PNG format. Did you check that it hasn't got corrupted somehow? How did you create `image_png`? Did you use `misc/scripts/png2c.py` from wxWidgets sources or some other way?

Comment: PNG support is enabled. I used both wxInclude.exe and png2c.py. The result was the same.

Comment: I don't see any reason for this to not work then. Try inserting these 2 lines into wxWidgets minimal sample, I'm quite sure it will work there. And so I suspect the problem might be actually the way you build your program, notably you may be building it with the different options from the ones used to build wxWidgets (you use `auto`, so you must be using C++11, but did you use C++11 compiler to build wx itself?).

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem (8 years later, maybe the API didn't exist at the time this question was asked) and fixed it by calling this function ([source (documentation for `wxBitmap::NewFromPNGData`)](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_bitmap.html#a2048897970d5e845040fcfc0259e1be1)):

```c
#include <wx/imagpng.h>


    wxInitAllImageHandlers()
```

It looks like you can also add individual handlers, but I haven't tried it yet: `wxImage::AddHandler(new wxPNGHandler);`

Documentation for [`wxInitAllImageHandlers()`](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__appinitterm.html#ga27f6c78d5d13374a28022b7bd44c6823)